# Joint speed: Kinect not counting time right using FPS

Tags: c#, kinect

I m trying to compute joint speed using the kinect. My algorythm to get the coordinates executes one time every 30 frames, thats how i did it:

This event runs everytime the kinect has a skeleton frame:

```
public void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
     //*default code to draw skeleton here*
     count++
     if (count == 30){
         //my code to acquire and display coordinates
         count = 0;
     }

 }
```

In theory, the part for coordinates acquisition should run every 1 second in real life (aproximattely), but thats not whats is happening. Its much faster then what it should be, but its NOT as fast as it runs when i dont use the if count.

The point is, id like to use this time interval between 2 joints capturing to compute speed, it would be (x1 - x2)/1 to have a m/s speed, since the coordinates are in meters.

I know this would be pretty inaccurate, but its just for testing.

I think the kinect isnt capturing in 30 frames per second, its much faster?

Is there any easier way to do this?

Oh and im using Visual C# and Kinect SDK

Comment: Consider computing elapsed time directly with `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` or `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinect capture in 40FPS (30 frames per seconds).
Theoretically speed defines as a movement in a cycle so each joint in 1/30 seconds has their own position so in each 30 frames you have movement in one second.
If you want to calculate it in an accurate way you must use some `timer` to calculate this timing for you instead of `counter` .
If having an accurate data is not important in your project you may store all the position of the joint in a list or array and then start to calculate based on the data in your list:
FYI in f=0, arr[0] has some value and in f=30, the value of the frame number 30 stored. so by calculating the distance between this two values you may find out your result.
Actually I used this method to calculate the average walking speeds.